# How to do an action if word not found in input, in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm using 'find' so that I can type in any sentence and as long as it finds a certain word, it will complete the action and continue. But now I dont know how to make it so if a wrong input is put in, it does a different action.
Here's some of my code:

```
:Menu2
echo.
echo What can I do for you?
echo.
set /p c=Command:
echo %c% | find /i "facebook" >NUL && Start Chrome http://www.facebook.com
echo %c% | find /i "youtube" >NUL && Start Chrome http://youtube.com
echo %c% | find /i "utube" >NUL && Start Chrome http://youtube.com
echo.
set random[0]=Of Course, Master.
set random[1]=Action completed, Master.
set random[2]=Completed Action.

set /a randomIDX=%random% * 3 / 32768

echo !random[%randomIDX%]!
echo.
goto :Menu2
pause
exit
```

I also have a random response put in to, but mainly I need to figure out how to make it 'goto' somewhere else if none of those words are found, right now it just continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set validcommand=youtube facebook utube
set /p c=Command:
for %%i in (%validcommand%) do if defined c echo %c% | find /i "%%i" >NUL && Start Chrome http://www.%%i.com&(set c=)
if defined c echo %c% is invalid&goto somewhereelse
```